# How to decrease the height of the map element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. Why am I not able to decrease the height of the `#map`?

As you can see the `.btn-enlarge` is enlarging the height of the image but the `.btn-shrink`is not decreasing the height

```js
$(function() {
  var unit = 10;
  
  $(".btn-enlarge").on("click", function(){
    unit = unit+ unit; 
    $("#map").animate({ 
                'height':  $("#map").height()+unit+ 'px'
                });
});
    $(".btn-shrink").on("click", function(){
    unit = unit+ unit; 
    $("#map").animate({ 
                'height':  $("#map").height()+'-'+unit+ 'px'
        });
});
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: move;
  overflow: hidden;
  Background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/a5/17/dda5177a3db95a93c0c84ff6847fda23.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" class="btn-shrink">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn-enlarge">+</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `+=` and `-=`

```js
jQuery(function( $ ) {

  var step = 10;

  $(".btn-enlarge, .btn-shrink").on("click", function() {
    var sym = $(this).is(".btn-enlarge") ? "+=" : "-=";
    $("#map").animate({height: sym + step});
  });
  
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/O724n.jpg') 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-shrink">-</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-enlarge">+</button>
<div id="map"></div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

The above's

```
$("#map").animate({height: sym + step});
```

translates to:

```
$("#map").animate({height: "+=10"}); // or
$("#map").animate({height: "-=10"}); // depending on the clicked button
```

Comment: Thanks a lots Roko but whatis `sym`

Comment: You're very welcome @Behseini `sym` is a variable. Stands for ***sym**bol* or *operator* if you wish. You can call it whatever you find fit. Everything else should be self-explanatory from the answer. BTW a shorthand for `a = a + 10` is `a += 10`. In jQuery it can be used to automagically increment a value as you can see in the example used like `"+=10"`.

Comment: If the `(statement) ? ifTrue : ifFalse` is a Ternary Operator AKA conditional operator.